# Python: Lock a file

Tags: python, locking

I have a Python app running on Linux. It is called every minute from cron. It checks a directory for files and if it finds one it processes it - this can take several minutes. I don't want the next cron job to pick up the file currently being processed so I lock it using the code below which calls portalocker. The problem is it doesn't seem to work. The next cron job manages to get a file handle returned for the file all ready being processed.

```
def open_and_lock(full_filename):
    file_handle = open(full_filename, 'r')
    try:
        portalocker.lock(file_handle, portalocker.LOCK_EX
                            | portalocker.LOCK_NB)
        return file_handle
    except IOError:
        sys.exit(-1)
```

Any ideas what I can do to lock the file so no other process can get it?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Winston Ewert I checked through the code and found the file handle was being closed way before the processing had finished. It seems to be working now except the second process blocks on portalocker.lock rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: does the second process manage to lock the file?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes as it returns from this call and reads the file

Comment: What do you do with the file handle that is returned from this function?

Comment: @Winston Ewert. Thanks for asking that question. I just checked through the code and found the file handle was being closed way before the processing had finished. It seems to be working now except the second process blocks on portalocker.lock rather than throws an exception

Comment: I get an exception when I run my simple test script.

Answer (score 9):

After fumbling with many schemes, this works in my case. I have a script that may be executed multiple times simultaneously. I need these instances to wait their turn to read/write to some files. The lockfile does not need to be deleted, so you avoid blocking all access if one script fails before deleting it.

```
import fcntl

def acquireLock():
    ''' acquire exclusive lock file access '''
    locked_file_descriptor = open('lockfile.LOCK', 'w+')
    fcntl.lockf(locked_file_descriptor, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
    return locked_file_descriptor

def releaseLock(locked_file_descriptor):
    ''' release exclusive lock file access '''
    locked_file_descriptor.close()

lock_fd = acquireLock()

# ... do stuff with exclusive access to your file(s)

releaseLock(lock_fd)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're using the LOCK_NB flag which means that the call is non-blocking and will just return immediately on failure. That is presumably happening in the second process. The reason why it is still able to read the file is that portalocker ultimately uses flock(2) locks, and, as mentioned in the [flock(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock):

> flock(2) places advisory locks only;
>   given suitable permissions on a file,
>   a process is free to ignore the use of
>   flock(2) and perform I/O on the file.

To fix it you could use the [fcntl.flock](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock) function directly (portalocker is just a thin wrapper around it on Linux) and check the returned value to see if the lock succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `cron` for this. Linux has [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), which can notify applications when a filesystem event occurs. There is a Python binding for `inotify` called [pyinotify](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify).

Thus, you don't need to lock the file -- you just need to react to `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events (i.e. when a file opened for writing was closed). (You also won't need to spawn a new process every minute.)

An alternative to using `pyinotify` is [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) which allows you to write an `incrontab` (very much in the same style as a crontab), to interact with the inotify system.

Comment: I guess the question has been solved in the comments already, but this is useful advice too.

Comment: Would I have to have a daemon process running to react to these notifications?

Comment: @Ambrosio: Yes, if you use pyinotify, the Python application would have to be running, and if you use `incron` then the `incrond` daemon would have to be running. Still, I think it is less resource-intensive than using `cron`+ 1 process every minute.

Answer (score 1):

what about manually creating an old-fashioned `.lock`-file next to the file you want to lock?

just check if it’s there; if not, create it, if it is, exit prematurely. after finishing, delete it.

Comment: This answer is correct (done properly).  Create a read-only file (the checking is implicit), if it already exists, it will return an error.

Comment: Lots of programs use this technique, like Skype and Truecrypt. They also all share the flaw that if they crash or shut down unexpectedly, then the end user must locate and delete all of its .lock files. This is definitely the wrong thing to do, so please use a proper locking library.

Comment: This answer is correct if it's implemented correctly. The thing most programs that use this are missing is a random string in the lock file. When you create the lock file, put a random string into it. Then read that string back - if it's the same, you have the lock. If it's not, wait for the lock file to not be there and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think [fcntl.lockf](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf) is what you are looking for.