# Prevent two python programms from writing to the same file at a time

Tags: python, file-io, locking

I run a python script several times in parallel on a cluster. All of them write to the same output file at the moment. This seems to cause defective lines. Is there a way to "lock" a file when one program writes into it and cause the other program to wait until the writing is finished? Or do I have to use multiple output files and unite them afterwards?

Comment: The latter option is the most easy (and fastest) to implement, and should cause the least problems. Your program can also continue, without waiting for the other one to write.

Comment: I would prefer second method as suggested by Mathias, How ever if you are interested in locking, then this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843359/python-lock-a-file

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [OS locking mechanism.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) If you really wanted that (since you mention a cluster, I assume you are on a Unix system). Problems with it:

- Waiting time: one process is writing, the rest are waiting for it to finish not doing work.
- Transfer time: your file would be in your home directory, physically sitting on the central node of your cluster. Each computer has to send the data through the network, that is even slower than writing to disk; relevant if they have to write a lot. (This actually depends on the details of the cluster). It is usually faster to write on the local hard drive and then send it to your directory when finished.
- Bug prone: the details of the implementation are quirky, and may require some experience to do it correctly.

If you really want to have only one file, I think your best option is to set up a listener process and send messages from each node to the master. This listener will have a stack that can be written in parallel, so you don't have to worry about processes waiting for each other. You of course have to make sure all the relevant processes are alive and working, and that you can write the data fast enough so the memory doesn't grow too fast.

To implement this you can opt for JSON RPC in the standard library, pyzmq (widely used in commercial production enviroments), or MPI (designed for high performance computing).

Comment: The explanations of you and the others sound logic to me. Since I am not forced to do a locking I guess I will use the second option using several output files. But thanks for showing me how it could be done!