# Portalocker does not exit as expected whereas fcntl does

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking, try-catch, fcntl

I do not understand why portalocker does not fail gracefully with the message "there is a lockfile". Instead, it fails with the following error:

```
portalocker.exceptions.LockException: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Note that the question has already been asked but no one has answered convincingly. see [python-lock-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843359/python-lock-a-file)
Here is the problematic script, which must be launched in two different consoles.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import portalocker
import sys

def open_and_lock(full_filename):
    file_handle = open(full_filename, 'w')
    try:
        portalocker.lock(file_handle, portalocker.LOCK_EX | portalocker.LOCK_NB)
        return file_handle
    except IOError:
        print ("there is a lockfile")
        sys.exit(-1)

# positioning a lock
lock_name = 'my_lock'
fh = open_and_lock(lock_name)

# do something consumer in time
i = 0
while (i < 100000000):
    i += 1
    print ("i :", i)

# lock release
close(fh)
```

Replace portalocker with fcntl and ... everything works fine!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import fcntl
import sys

def open_and_lock(full_filename):
    file_handle = open(full_filename, 'w')
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(file_handle, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        return file_handle
    except IOError:
        print ("there is a lockfile")
        sys.exit(-1)

# positioning a lock
lock_name = 'my_lock'
fh = open_and_lock(lock_name)

# do something consumer in time
i = 0
while (i < 100000000):
    i += 1
    print ("i :", i)

# lock release
close(fh)
```

What is going on ? why this difference in behavior between portalocker and fcntl?

ps:
Python 3.6.7
Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

The exception *is* a graceful one: `portalocker.exceptions.LockException`

As opposed to directly using `fcntl`, `portalocker` wraps the exceptions so it works on multiple platforms. The `fcntl` example wouldn't work on Windows, `portalocker` does :)

The tests show some useful examples: https://github.com/WoLpH/portalocker/blob/develop/portalocker_tests/tests.py

In your case, instead of capturing `IOError` you should capture `portalocker.exceptions.LockException`. And additionally you should always properly unlock as well so I would propose the following instead:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import portalocker
import sys


# positioning a lock
lock_name = 'my_lock'

try:
    with portalocker.Lock(lock_name, portalocker.LOCK_EX | portalocker.LOCK_NB):
        # do something consumer in time
        i = 0
        while (i < 100000000):
            i += 1
            print ("i :", i)
except portalocker.exceptions.LockException:
    print ("there is a lockfile")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Or if you really want to explicitly lock and unlock:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import portalocker
import sys

def open_and_lock(full_filename):
    file_handle = open(full_filename, 'w')
    try:
        portalocker.lock(file_handle, portalocker.LOCK_EX | portalocker.LOCK_NB)
        return file_handle
    except portalocker.exceptions.LockException:
        print ("there is a lockfile")
        sys.exit(-1)

# positioning a lock
lock_name = 'my_lock'
fh = open_and_lock(lock_name)

try:
    # do something consumer in time
    i = 0
    while (i < 100000000):
        i += 1
        print ("i :", i)
finally:
    # lock release
    portalocker.unlock(fh)
```